# Can't define Node_ENV in Webpack

Tags: configuration, webpack, feathersjs

I am trying to use webpack but have this issue with the ENV when using feathers-configuration pack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEnv' of undefined
        at Function.<anonymous> (vendor.npm.js:37275)
        at Function.configure (vendor.npm.js:27533)
        at Object.59 (index.js:38)
        at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js:51)
        at Object.0 (index.js:8)
        at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js:51)
        at webpackJsonpCallback (manifest.js:22)
        at index.js:1
```

The error in the vendor.npm.js package is. Feathers-configuration is using the config.getEnv method and can't find NODE_ENV.

```
var env = config.util.getEnv('NODE_ENV');
```

I am even trying to use the defineplugin but it doesn't work:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                DEBUG: true,
                "process.env":{
                    "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
                }
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use below  plugin  https://www.npmjs.com/package/extended-define-webpack-plugin

// webpack.config.js

```
var ExtendedDefinePlugin = require('extended-define-webpack-plugin');
var appConfig = require('./app.config.js');

module.exports = {
  // ... 
  plugins: [
    /* ..., */
    new ExtendedDefinePlugin({
      APP_CONFIG: appConfig,
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Tried and still doesn't work: new ExtendedDefinePlugin({
     "NODE_ENV": "production"
   }),